# Raising the entries of a matrix by column

Tags: r

I need to create a function (x,k), were x= vector of length n, and k=integer. 
The function needs to give me a matrix of dimensions [n x k], and the entries in each column need to be raised to the power of the number of that column (ie. in column one the entries are x, in column 2 the entries are x^2, etc). 
I'm having a hard time figuring it out how to structure a function that would do this type of operation by column.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this probably, taking advantage of `outer`, which returns a `matrix` as a result of applying a function to the two vectors.

```
matpower <- function(x,k) outer(x,seq_len(k),`^`)
matpower(1:4,4)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1
#[2,]    2    4    8   16
#[3,]    3    9   27   81
#[4,]    4   16   64  256
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And you know how can I add specific names to each one of the columns? I want to name them "x, x^2,x^3...", but I'm not finding how to do this.

Comment: @cramosv - you've got most of your answer, now's the time for you to do a bit more research yourself!